# Please identify this WW1 Italian Uniform

Tags: world-war-one, identification, italy, uniform

Can you tell me anything about the uniform in the picture? I believe the picture was taken around the time of the first WW in Sicily. The insignia on the hat, the hat itself, the boots and sword makes me suspect cavalry. The boy looks young though so I'm thinking military school. If someone could ID time and place, rank division etc. Thank you so much[image: young boy in militaristic uniform]

Comment: Hi Gennaro and welcome to History SE. Can you give the dimensions of the photo? Also, is there anything on the back? These may help with dating the photo.

Answer (score 4):

I think this photo was taken after WW1,

I can say you that this is the uniform model 1926 that was  superseeded by the uniform M1934, so the lapse of time is from 1926 since 1934.

This is a cavalry uniform, because the cavalry's fatigue hat, the cavalry pants and the leather leggings, the cap's badge is that of the Cavalry School, or Cavalry remount centres or cavalry's depots, and this further suggests which the photo was taken after WW1 because this specialization didn't received a cap's badge during WW1.

I think he was a private because if he was a NCO he should wore the chevrons on the sleeves, while if he was an officer he should had metal stars on the shoulder's straps.

The headquarters of the Cavalry School was in Pinerolo, near Turin, the collar flashes color was yellow.

I hope I have been helpful to you,
A hug from Italy,